# Google Form submit running unknown sheet app script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api, google-forms

I have a very strange problem.  I have a google form and an attached sheet.  That sheet has a script which seems to run OK (I just have it doing a betterlogger on form submit).  Here's the strange thing - throughout the day I have been creating forms and scripts bound in sheets.  Now, for some reason, one form I have is running a script that is not bound to it (well, it must be bound but I cannot see it when I edit the scripts).  No matter what I have tried, this sheet continues to run some mystery script of mine (I can tell because it too has betterlogger output that gets merged with the "correct" script attached to the sheet).  To summarize, I have a script bound to a sheet that runs correctly but in parallel, another one of my sheet scripts runs at the same time - I have no way to tell which other script it is since I have many.  This mystery script runs  even if the sheet has NO triggers defined for the sheet script!

Is there any way to see "all" bound scripts for a sheet or form?  Are there hidden ones that I can see or disconnect from?

Comment: If you go to 'all triggers' do you see grey triggers? They indicate that you are using triggers in other projects.

Comment: Yes, there are many other triggers in other projects.  That seems irrelevant to me since I am saying that I have a given sheet that is executing a script that is neither bound to it nor does this sheet have a trigger defines.  When my form is submitted, it is running an app script that is neither bound to this sheet nor is there and kind of trigger defined...

Comment: My question about being able to see all bound sheets and triggers for a sheet is NOT what the "all trigggers" display shows - it just shows you all triggers you have ever defined for all sheets you have (and terribly, it gives you no indication of which sheets those triggers are attached to).  I need a feature where I can see all scripts that are bound to a given sheet since in my case a mysterious script is running for my sheet but I can't tell which script it is.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this is a known bug in the google app script / sheets world.  It rarely occurs but there are references to it.  See here: https://plus.google.com/111635744893768700770/posts/SBeeu9KwWfL